# I have an error when running my Django application

Tags: python, django

I'm following a tutorial on deploying a machine learning model via django framework. Here's the link to the tutorial [Link1](https://www.deploymachinelearning.com/train-ml-models/)
I followed all the steps correctly up to step 3. First, I wrote all the code myself. Seeing that my application wasn't working, I copied and pasted all the Django code from the site.
Here's the link to my project on gitHub [Link2](https://github.com/seydoug007/my_ml_service2.git)

I'm using `python 3.6`
and `django==2.2.4`

When I run `python manage.py runserver` in my terminal, I get this error message:

```
(venv) C:\Users\SEYDOU GORO\my_ml_service2\backend\server>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SEYDOU GORO\my_ml_service2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 604, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SEYDOU GORO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\SEYDOU GORO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SEYDOU GORO\my_ml_service2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SEYDOU GORO\my_ml_service2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\SEYDOU GORO\my_ml_service2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 423, in check
    databases=databases,
  File "C:\Users\SEYDOU GORO\my_ml_service2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\SEYDOU GORO\my_ml_service2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\SEYDOU GORO\my_ml_service2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\SEYDOU GORO\my_ml_service2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 416, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\SEYDOU GORO\my_ml_service2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\SEYDOU GORO\my_ml_service2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 611, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'server.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

I don't know what's going on, but I need help to understand what's going on.

Comment: Sorry all the files wasn'i in github now I have updated my github after the posting

Answer (score 1):

In [Django Documentation: URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/) there are examples about how to **including other URLconfs**.

```py
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    # ... snip ...
    path('community/', include('aggregator.urls')),
    path('contact/', include('contact.urls')),
    # ... snip ...
]
```

You missed `include()` in `backend/server/server/urls.py`, and this causes the error `The included URLconf 'server.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it.`.

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

See the difference?

Answer (score 1):

** main urls.py (this file is in the same directory as settings.py)

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # ... snip ...
    path('community/', include('aggregator.urls')),
    path('contact/', include('contact.urls')),
    # ... snip ...
]
```

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I solved the problem, it was just a small typo in the code that I corrected. It was just an odd word that wasn't supposed to be in my code. I wonder if I should close this post

Comment: You're welcome, maybe it will help someone else with the same error.